# How to find $\lim_{ \| {\bf x} \| \to 0} \frac{ \left( <{\bf x},{\bf y}> \right)^2}{\| {\bf x} \|^2 }$

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, inner-products

Let ${\bf x}$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\|{\bf x}\|=r$.

I want to find the following limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{r \to 0}   \frac{ \left(Tr({\bf x} {\bf y}^T) \right)^2}{r^2}
\end{align}

for some ${\bf y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Or in other words, by using the language of inner products and norms
\begin{align}
\lim_{ \| {\bf x} \| \to 0}   \frac{ \left( <{\bf x},{\bf y}> \right)^2}{\| {\bf x} \|^2 }
\end{align}

By Cauchy-Scwart, we can show that

\begin{align}
\lim_{ \| {\bf x} \| \to 0}   \frac{ \left( <{\bf x},{\bf y}> \right)^2}{\| {\bf x} \|^2 } \le  \lim_{ \| {\bf x} \| \to 0}   \frac{ \|{\bf x}\|^2 \|{\bf y}\|^2}{\|{\bf x}\|^2} \le  \|{\bf y}\|^2
\end{align}

Note, that for the case of $n=1$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(xy)^2}{x^2}=y^2
\end{align}

Comment: I think the most difficult step is proving that there is a limit. Indeed, once you know this, picking $x$ to be colinear with $y$ and of norm $r$ should give you the solution

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit doesn't exist. You could pick $x$ with $\|x\| = r$ so that $\langle x,y \rangle = 0$, or $\langle x,y \rangle = r\|y\|$, or anything in between. As $r \to 0$ you could get any value in between $0$ and $\|y\|^2$.